# Linking to UK addresses from TextView AutoLink=Map

Tags: android, dictionary, textview, autolink

I'm new to android development and been trying to use the autolink feature of a TextView to allow linking to show a UK address in Google Maps. I'm using android sdk 4.2 with a Nexus 7.

I can't get the textview autolink feature to recognize a UK address and make it linkable. If I put in a US address as a test it works perfectly so I'm pretty sure the method is ok, it's just that the address is not recognized.

Does anyone know if this feature is meant to work with UK addresses and if so does the address need to be a specific format to be recognized?

I've searched for an answer and saw one message from 2005 saying it was US addresses only. I asked a similar message in android development group but the message didn't appear so I'm not sure if I'm meant to ask a message like this there.

Thanks
John.

Comment: Please add code, reference "one message from 2005" and last but not least examples of the addresses which work and which do not work.